# VGA Problem in ubuntu 12.4 DELL N5110

Tags: intel-graphics

i just **upgraded from 11.10 to 12.4** , now my **Intel HD** and **Nvidia 525** graphic cards is not  installed and in additional hardware it cant find them... 
any solution ??? by the way i used bumblebee to reach more power on my Laptop.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually by design, Optimus laptops are currently not supported by the driver "as is" and will after installation break your desktop (unless you use Bumblebee).

This "bug" is reported at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jockey/+bug/983202

You may still manually install the driver by installing the `nvidia-current` package, but it's not recommended. Instead, I suggest you to [install Bumblebee](https://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969) which will take care of pulling the driver and configuring it to not break the desktop.

Comment: no way :( it seems i could reinstall the ubuntu 12.4 may be its because the old packages

Comment: Why do you want to reinstall? Additional drivers will still be empty.